# When using memory optimized tables, should the database size not exceed RAM size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

In SQL Server 2016, if we create a database in RAM (i.e using memory optimized tables), the database size should not exceed RAM size, am I right in saying that?

Comment: Maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be better to ask this question.

Comment: @user3653116: you might want to consider accepting answers(you haven't accepted any) : if you don't, in the long term people might be less inclined to help you.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2016 memory-optimized tables require that sufficient memory exist to keep **all** of the rows ***and*** indexes in memory.

- [Requirements for Using Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/requirements-for-using-memory-optimized-tables)
- [Estimate Memory Requirements for Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/estimate-memory-requirements-for-memory-optimized-tables)

> The size of a memory-optimized table corresponds to the size of data
>   plus some overhead for row headers. When migrating a disk-based table
>   to memory-optimized, the size of the memory-optimized table will
>   roughly correspond to the size of the clustered index or heap of the
>   original disk-based table.

You wouldn't normally create all your database tables as memory-optimised tables, only those with high throughput/insertion OLTP workloads.

So before you go converting all your tables to memory-optimised tables, first identify those with high activity, convert and then measure any performance increase (and monitor RAM usage).

Comment: Not only that, you're unlikely to see any performance improvements without using associated memory optimised stored procedures

Comment: Hi @Nick; I think you will see a perf increase for non-durable tables without using associated memory optimised stored procedures as there will be no TLog activity.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but in my brief experience, there wasn't any difference. It certainly wasn't a scientific investigation though. Perhaps the TLog wasn't a bottleneck in my case.

Comment: >>>you're unlikely to see any performance improvements without using associated memory optimised stored procedures<<< That is not true. Even without natively compiled sp in highLY loaded OLTP there is performance gain on insert due to lack of LOCKS

Comment: Interesting - I did some brief reading. My experience is only with bulk data loads against non durable tables rather than highly contentious tables so I guess you can expect to see more of a difference there.